# How to order groupings in MantineReactTable?

Tags: reactjs, mantine

I have build the following MantineReactTable:

```
const columns = useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef<DestinationViewModel>[]>(
        () => [
            {
                header: 'Status',
                accessorKey: 'status',
            },
            {
                header: 'Id',
                accessorKey: 'id',
            },
            {
                header: 'Tag',
                accessorKey: 'name',
            },
            {
                header: 'Created On',
                accessorKey: 'createdOn',
            },
            {
                header: 'Position',
                accessorKey: 'position',
            },
            {
                header: 'Vehicle-ID',
                accessorKey: 'vehicleId',
            },
            {
                header: 'Vehicle',
                accessorKey: 'vehicleName',
            },
        ],
        [],
    );

    const data: DestinationViewModel[] = missions.map((task) => ({
        id: `#${task.id.substring(0, 5)}`,
        fullId: task.id,
        name: task.name,
        position: `${task.toLatitude}, ${task.toLongitude}`,
        createdOn: task.createdOn.toString(),
        vehicleId: task.vehicleId,
        vehicleName: task.vehicleName,
        status: task.status === DestinationStatus.pending ? "Pending"
            : task.status === DestinationStatus.active ? "Active"
                : task.status === DestinationStatus.completed ? "Completed"
                    : "Unknown",
    }));
<MantineReactTable
                    columns={columns}
                    data={data}
                    enableGrouping
                    enableStickyHeader
                    enableStickyFooter
                    initialState={{
                        density: 'xs',
                        expanded: true,
                        grouping: ['status'],
                        pagination: {pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 50},
                    }}
                    mantineToolbarAlertBannerBadgeProps={{
                        color: 'blue',
                        variant: 'outline'
                    }}
                    mantineTableContainerProps={{
                        sx: {maxHeight: 700}
                    }}
                    mantineTableBodyRowProps={({row}) => ({
                        sx: {
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                        },
                    })}
                    enableRowActions
                    renderRowActions={({row}) => row.original.status === "Pending" ? (
                        <Box sx={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'nowrap', gap: '8px'}}>
                            <Button
                                sx={(theme) => ({
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    color: 'black',
                                    backgroundColor: "#e9f74f",
                                    '&:hover': {
                                        backgroundColor: "#c0cc41",
                                    },
                                })}
                                onClick={() => onOpenActivateMissionModal(row.original)}
                                variant="filled"
                                mt="md"
                                radius="lg">Activate</Button>
                        </Box>
                    ) : row.original.status === "Active" ? (
                        <Box sx={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'nowrap', gap: '8px'}}>
                            <Button
                                sx={(theme) => ({
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    color: 'black',
                                    backgroundColor: "#e9f74f",
                                    '&:hover': {
                                        backgroundColor: "#c0cc41",
                                    },
                                })}
                                onClick={() => onOpenCompleteMissionModal(row.original)}
                                variant="filled"
                                mt="md"
                                radius="lg">Complete</Button>
                        </Box>
                    ) : null}
                    localization={MRT_Localization_EN}/>
```

This results in the following table:
[MantineReatTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzNeV.png)

How can I order the groupings? There will be a third "Active" status. In the table, the pending entries should be on top, followed by the active ones. The completed ones should go third.

I already check if the initialState of the MantineReactTable component provides suiting properties, but I couldn't find any.